# Dynamic URL using useParams for one component is not working when linked from another component (MUI breadcrumbs with react-router-dom)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-router-dom, breadcrumbs

Let say there are three components:

- ComponentA (Content)
- ComponentB (BlogRepo)
- ComponentC (CreateBlog)

Component hierarchy and their URLs are like:

- Content (https://localhost/content)

  - BlogRepo (https://localhost/content/<blog_repo_id>)

    - CreateBlog (https://localhost/content/createblog/?blogrepoId=xxxxxx))

Routes are defined in app.js as using `BrowserRouter`:

```
  <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/content"
          element={
            <RequireAuth>
              <Content/>
            </RequireAuth>
          }
        />
        <Route
          path="/content/:bgid"
          element={
            <RequireAuth>
              <BlogsRepo/>
            </RequireAuth>
          }

        />
        <Route
          path="/createblog"
          element={
            <RequireAuth>
              <CreateBlog/>
            </RequireAuth>
          }
        />
        <Route path="*" element={<ErrorPage />} />
      </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

As there are many Blogs Repo(something like a Space), each one is identified by an id which is used to render the page. Hence for (https://localhost/content/<blog_repo_id>) I am using the useParams to pass the blog_id to react-router-dom and its working well.

While creating the blog, I am using the https://mui.com/material-ui/react-breadcrumbs/ to display the path of the Blog Repo under which we are creating the blog. It should be something like:

[Content](https://localhost:3000/content) / [Blog Repos](https://localhost:3000/content/xxxxxx) / createblog

Now using the above breadcrubms link, I can go to content but when trying to go to Blog Repos, its using the correct URL but not able to show the content.

Link used for Blog Repos:

```
<Link
    underline="hover"
    sx={{ color: "primary", fontSize: "15px" }}
    href={`/content/${blogrepoid}`}
    >
    {blogreponame}
</Link>
```

I am using `location.search` to get the blogrepoid and to generate the required string. But as its not mapped to the BlogRepos component from where the actual blogrepoid has been rendered, its not able to display the content of the https://localhost:3000/content/xxxxxx after clicking the [Blog Repos](https://localhost:3000/content/xxxxxx) link and the page is showing blank.

Is there any we can make this link to work ?

Comment: Should the create blog path be `"/content/createblog"`? I see no hierarchy with the routes *other than* by the path designation. I also don't understand what you are saying is an issue. Can you [edit] to share a more complete [mcve] that includes the components you are trying to render and how you are trying to link to them?

Comment: @DrewReese createblog path is fine and working well. But in the createblog page, I am trying to add a breadcrumbs at the top of the page which will be a hyperlink to other pages based on their hierarchy. All the pages are working well except the BlogRepos as its having an id coming from `location.search` to dynamically generate the URL.

Comment: The create blog's breadcrumb path would be "create blog", based on the route structure, right? It is not a sub-route of the `"/content"` path segment in the routes configuration. I'm not sure what you could breadcrumb to from the create blog page. Are you instead wanting the breadcrumb to be a "trail" of the pages the user navigated to in the `"/content/:bgid"` "flow" before clicking a button or whatever to create a blog entry? It's a bit unclear what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Here issue is not with createblog but with BlogsRepo. Blogrepo path is getting generated from the blog_repo_id which is used via `/content/:bgid` router path and  useParams. Hence apart from BlogRepo page, that link is not working anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it using `navigate(-1)`. Even though not very happy with this solution, but its working.

Here is what I did:

Created the below one in the function level:

```
const handleClick = () => {
    navigate(-1);
  };
```

And then return it under the `Link` for breadcrumbs:

```
<Link
    underline="hover"
    sx={{ color: "primary", fontSize: "15px" }}
    onClick={handleClick}
>
```

For some reason, `href` with a variable id is not working under `breadcrumbs`.